# Парсинг веб-страницы, обработка JS

Tags: javascript, c#, парсер

Есть страница, данные на которой частично обрабатываются JS. Приложение на C#, делаю запрос через HttpClient (пробовал и через WebClient) - но, естественно, на выходе не получаю желаемого результата. Как заставить JS сначала обработать эту страницу, а потом только ее загрузить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приюзать стандартный компонент браузера, предположу?
p.s. как уже написали - да, здесь маловато подробностей. 
Можно приюзать класс (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)
Т.е. код примерно такой :

```
private void browserProgress(e WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) {
    if (e.CurrentProgress == e.MaximumProgress) {
        waitForReady();
    }
}

browser = new WebBrowser()
browser.Navigate(URL)
browser.OnProgressChanged += browserProgress
```

Правда, возникает вопрос - как реализовать waitForReady? Никаких событий, связанных с работой с DOM я не нашел. Как вариант - по достижении waitForReady стартовать такймер, провять по таймеру готовность и по готовности останавливать. Но это какой-то очень кривой метод.

Comment: Ну, поначалу я только указал на то, что надо смотреть в сторону браузера - подробности добавил уже позже.

Comment: @PashaPash посмотрите историю содержимого ответа. На наш взгляд, он был более похож на вопрос нежели ответ. Текущий вариант ответа гораздо лучше.

Comment: Можно здесь (как крайний случай) имитировать задержку в несколько секунд ?

Comment: ИМХО, если уж юзать задержки - то создавать и запускать стандартный таймер (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) с небольшим интервалом, по таймеру - проверять готовность нужных данных и по готовности - обрабатывать их и уничтожать таймер.

Comment: @Alex ок, согласен, первая ревизия смотрелась странно :)